# Entering a series of commands in git bash through java code

Tags: java, git-bash

Am trying to get a series of commands on git bash one after the other. I can open the terminal through the code but after that wasn't successful with entering anything. For instance this is the code I tried

```
 String [] args = new String[] {"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"};
                String something="hi how are you doing";

                try {
                    ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
                    var proc = p.command(args).start();
                    var w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));
                    w.write(something);
                } catch (IOException ioException){
                    System.out.println(ioException);
                }
```

Please let know how to be able to do enter a series of commands into git bash through the code.

Comment: What do you need to actually do?

Comment: I want to enter a series of commands after the terminal opens. I was thinking of making a basic UI interface with some buttons wherein when I click on a button then some actions follow in the terminal. Commands like this I enter into the terminal - export REGISTRY_IP=$(kubectl get service eclipse-hono-service-device-registry-ext --output="jsonpath={.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0]['hostname','ip']}" -n hono)
export HTTP_ADAPTER_IP=$(kubectl get service eclipse-hono-adapter-http-vertx --output="jsonpath={.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0]['hostname','ip']}" -n hono)

Comment: The normal place to do such exports is in the bash configuration file.  Sure that will not do for you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the command `git-bash.exe` opens the terminal window but the window's input is still the keyboard, so trying to write to the `OutputStream` that is returned by method `getOutputStream()`, in class `Process` does nothing. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244536/how-to-display-the-contents-of-a-txt-file-on-cmd-window-using-java/63252584#63252584) question.

As an alternative, I suggest using using `ProcessBuilder` to execute a series of individual `git` commands. When you do that, your java code gets the command output.

Here is a simple example that displays the `git` version.

```java
import java.io.IOException;

public class ProcBldT4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe
        // C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe", "--version");
        pb.inheritIO();
        try {
            Process proc = pb.start();
            int exitStatus = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println(exitStatus);
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When you run the above code, the `git` version details will be written to `System.out`.

Also, if the `git` command fails, the error details are written to `System.err`.

You need to repeat the code above for each, individual `git` command that you need to issue.