# Running multiple jar files using Process runtime

Tags: java

I have many test cases in jar files. These files, together with their paths, are listed in an excel sheet. My test automation will read this excel sheet, and run the jar files (the test case) using

```
Process process = RUntime.getRUntime().exec("process name");
```

To iterate the excel sheet, I implement a for loop.

My expectation is that whn the process runs the first jar, say test1.jar, this test should be completed first, then due to the for loop, it executes the second jar, say test2.jar.

I also need to be able to monitor the progress of the test via the cmd console.

Hope to have advice on how to acheive this.

**Update:**
As per requested, I have the following code to do the iteration:

```
for(start.count = 1; start.count <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); start.count++){  
            System.out.println("Total test case = " + sheet.getLastRowNum());
            System.out.println(start.count);
            final XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(start.count);
            start.testability = row.getCell(0).toString();            
            start.jar_filepath = row.getCell(1).toString();
            start.tc_name = row.getCell(2).toString();
            start.test_data = row.getCell(3).toString();
            start.test_result = row.getCell(4).toString();
            start.test_cycle = df.formatCellValue(row.getCell(5));
            System.out.println("test cycle from start.jar = " + start.test_cycle);
            System.out.println("Test Case Name : " + start.tc_name);
            if (start.testability.equals("Y") || start.testability.equals("y)")) {
                System.out.println("Test Case Name : " + start.tc_name);
                System.out.println("Round : " + start.count);
                final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k  java -jar " + start.jar_filepath + " " + start.tc_name + " " + start.test_data + " " + start.test_result + " " + start.test_cycle);
                p.waitFor();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("This this case is not tested");
            }          
}//for
System.out.println("test is done");
```

What happen is in the Eclipse console, the loops are being iterated, but only the test1.jar is executed. Once the test is done, test2.jar is not executed.

How do I get test2.jar to be executed after test1.jar is finished ?

I have tried with process builder as follows :

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd/c start cmd /k java -jar " + start.jar_filepath + " " + start.tc_name + " " + start.test_data + " " + start.test_result + " " + start.test_cycle).start();
```

but it is giving my the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd/c start cmd /k java -jar C:\TA\Jar\TC_Reload.jar Reload C:\\TA\\TD\\TD.xlsx C:\\TA\\TR\\ ": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at start.main(start.java:50)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Have you written code that does not meet your expectation? If you have, then I suggest that you [edit] your question and post it. If you have not written code, then what answer are you hoping to get for your question? By the way, consider using class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) rather than `Runtime`.

Comment: @Abra, I have updated with my code.

Comment: Desperately need help on this.

Comment: The exception you post relates to trying to run `cmd/c` which probably isn't an executable. What happens when you run `cmd /c` ?

Comment: Also -- you probably won't be able to use `Runtime.exec()` on a process that produces output, unless you make some provision to collect the output. `exec()` will just block.

Comment: @KevinBoone I have tried modifying my ProcessBuilder to just run  cmd /c and it still results in the same error. Or do you mean run ````cmd /c```` at WIndows >> Search ? When I do that, the cmd comes out momentarily and closes, just like it suppose to. But how come it can be executed using Runtime.exec()? By the way, from your explanation, I should be catching the output, and then do a condtion test to it to ascertain whetheer to continue the run ?

Comment: If you're getting an `IOException`, there's not point capturing the output, because the program has not started. The error message you posted earlier was perfectly clear: "Cannot run program cmd/c start ,,, error=2, The system cannot find the file specified" An exception like this indicates a fault in your command-line -- or that 'cmd.exe' actually can't be found, which would be a platform problem.

Comment: @KevinBoone Noted. Just curious why Process.Runtime() can execute it, but not ProcessBUilder().

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244536/how-to-display-the-contents-of-a-txt-file-on-cmd-window-using-java/63252584#63252584