# Create Process with console/terminal

Tags: java

The [Process javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html) says:

> By default, the created process does not have its own terminal or console.

Is there actually a way to create a terminal/console with the process, other than faking it by creating a custom UI where stdout/err is directed?

Comment: Why do you regard "creating a custom UI where stdout/err is directed" as "faking" a console? How do you think "real" terminals/consoles are created? What is a "real" terminal in your mind?

Comment: There's a distinct difference between making your own UI versus using `cmd` or the system equivalent.

Comment: Are you interested in using [`ProcessBuiler.inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) to forward IO to the **current** terminal or console? Or are you strictly wanting some new terminal to start in a window? Because that would be operating system specific. And you wouldn't really be able to control the input output from the parent process. So your question is just too vague.

Comment: The latter. And yeah, I'm aware that it would be system-dependent. But given the line in the javadoc, I was curious if there was actually some built-in way to do this. (after all, a "default" seems to imply a way to change from the default)

Comment: Technically there isn't any difference. `cmd` is also just another UI where the output streams of the process are directed to. Do you just want to use the system terminal to display your process's output?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, exactly, but without relying on any existing system terminal (for example, we might be running from javaw)

Comment: "cmd.exe" and console windows are different things in Windows' cmd.exe has the same status as any program linked for the so-called console subsystem - it gets a new console window if it does not inherit one.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? [How to display the contents of a .txt file on cmd window using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244536/how-to-display-the-contents-of-a-txt-file-on-cmd-window-using-java)